# Pandas: convert column to datetime format

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas column `['Date']` which has of the type `datetime.datetime` and looks like `2014-07-30 00:00:00`. Now I want to convert it to the same datatype datetime.datetime but minus the time that is `2014-07-30` .

I tried a bunch of stuff like:

```
df['PSG Date '] =  pd.to_datetime(df['PSG Date '], format='%Y-%m-%-d %H:%M:%S')
```

but it didn't work.

edit

```
a=df['PSG Date '].iloc[0]
print(a,type(a))
```

gives `<class 'datetime.datetime'>`

doing `df['PSG Date '] = df['PSG Date '].dt.date` gives -

```
AttributeError: Can only use .dt accessor with datetimelike values
```

printing `df['PSG Date']` gives the column with values like `2013-10-30 00:00:00` so on

Comment: @AntonvBR     I had tried this solution already as I had mentioned in the question but I got AttributeError: Can only use .dt accessor with datetimelike values

Comment: even though doing a=df['PSG Date '].iloc[0]  print(a,type(a)) gives <class 'datetime.datetime'>

Comment: @AntonvBR yes I have answered your question

Comment: @AntonvBR...I added the changes to question

Comment: Ok but can you print your column and post your data too? use `print(df.head(5)['PSG Date '])` for instance

Comment: Can you try: `pd.to_datetime(df['PSG Date '].astype(str), format='%Y-%m-%-d %H:%M:%S')`

Comment: @AntonvBR it is showing ValueError: '-' is a bad directive in format '%Y-%m-%-d %H:%M:%S'

Comment: Ok then please try this: `pd.to_datetime(df['PSG Date '].astype(str), format='%Y-%m%-d %H:%M:%S', errors='coerce')`. **OR WAIT NOW....** I think I identified your problem!!! `%Y-%m-%-d` should be `%Y-%m-%d`

Comment: @AntonvBR wont the errors=coerce ignore a few rows?

Comment: Yes it would if there are errors. But try the last row. I think you error lies in a missplaced `-`. **%Y-%m-%d**

Comment: @AntonvBR doing %Y-%m-%d is gving ValueError: time data - doesn't match format specified......

Comment: Put `errors='coerce'` and look how many rows are wrong. You will need to investigate your data!

Comment: @AntonvBR by printing the data and type I am getting 2014-07-30 00:00:00 <class 'datetime.datetime'>....isnt the format ='%Y-%m%-d %H:%M:%S' correct in this case?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174807/discussion-between-ubuntu-noob-and-anton-vbr).